# The debugger of vscode is not working(variables,watch, call stack), the "call stack" will appear but stop suddenly

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging

The debugger of vscode is not working(variables,watch, call stack), the result of the console.log() appear in terminal and the "call stack" will appear but stop suddenly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q0Nk.png)

my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\src\\index.ts",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

my code

```
let nome: string = "brother"
let age : number = 20
if(age<100){
    age +=10
}
console.log(age)
```

Restart the vscode and Uninstall python extension

Comment: what part does not work ? did you try to put a break point ? I dont see any break point at the image you shared. you can find the latest launch config {here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-debugging)